# how to solve the requested URL returned error: 403 on bitbucket? and setup to push both on github and bitbucket?

Tags: github, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-keys

I forked a repo from bitbucket for my internship test. I worked on it. then I did:

1. git init
2. hub create

now when i have to push to bit bucket and I want
to push also on github but i get this error:

> unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/aaa/bbb.git/': The requested
> URL returned error: 403

I never used bitbucket and always github. I wanna be able to use both. The repo is open to everyone and I need to make a pull request to let them evaluate my code. I dont understand how need to install ssh key/bitbucket credentials on my local machine to access it. It seems confusing.

DOES anyone have any clue how to set up both bitbucket and github and fixing this error? I have to hand in by the end of the week and I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

> The repo is open to everyone

For pulling/cloning, yes, it is opened to everyone, not for pushing.

Only the owner/collaborators of the bitbucket.org/aaa/bbb.git can push to it, so if you want to make a pull request from a BitBucker repository, you need to push to to your fork, not the original repository.

You can push to [multiple repositories](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242):

```sh
git remote set-url --add --push origin https://github.com/<you>/<yourRepo>
git remote set-url --add --push origin https://bitbucket.org/<you>/<yourFork>
# Or, if you are using a registered SSH key to your BitBucket account
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@bitbucket.org:<you>/<yourFork>
```

Comment: thanks VonC, I am a bit lost. It seems i dont have a SSH keys and i honestly i am not sure how to differentiate it with git hub. quite lost

Comment: @user14749773 I was mentioning SSH only because you have "ssh-keys" in your question tags. In your case, use HTTPS, but mainly use the URL of your fork, that you have created and that you own. (as in "I forked a repo from bitbucket": assuming you have forked it on BitBucket)